# Why does this regex with a 2-byte unicode char emit "uninitialized" warning for the lvalue on match?

Tags: regex, perl, unicode

The following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use utf8;
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.012; # implicitly turn on feature unicode_strings
my $test = "some string";
$test =~ m/.+\x{2013}/x;
```

Yields:

> Use of uninitialized value `$test` in pattern match `(m//)` at test.pl line 9.

This seems to happen with any 2-byte character inside `\x{}`. The following regexes work fine:

```
/a+\x{2013}/
/.*\x{2013}/
/.+\x{20}/
```

Also, the error goes away with `use bytes`, but using that pragma is [discouraged](http://perldoc.perl.org/bytes.html). What's going on here?

Comment: Confirmed on perl 5.16.1. I think you should post this as a perl bug report instead of an SO question; all we can do is get philosophical about it :)

Comment: I'm vaguely hoping that this is my error, but you're right -- it looks like it might just be a bug. I'm testing on v5.14.2, BTW.

Comment: Workaround: Add `utf8::upgrade($test);` before the match.

Comment: Still exists in fresh 5.17.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is singular that you should ask this question. I looks related to a bug that I just reported yesterday

[`https://rt.perl.org/rt3/Ticket/Display.html?id=114808`](https://rt.perl.org/rt3/Ticket/Display.html?id=114808)

where this code also produces `"Use of uninitialized value $_ in split ..."` warnings, and causes `split` to unexpectedly return an empty list:

```
use warnings;
binmode *STDOUT, ":encoding(UTF-8)";
my $pattern = "\x{abc}\x{def}ghi";
for ( "\x{444}", "norm\x{a0}l", "\x{445}", "ab\x{ccc}de\x{fff}gh" ) {
  print "--------------------\ntext is $_, pattern is /$pattern/\n";

  # expect  split  to return  ($_) , but when $pattern and $_ both
  # have wide chars, it returns  ()
  print 'split output is [', split /$pattern/, $_;

  print "]\n";
}
```

Comment: this should probably be a comment

Comment: okay, looks like this is a bug, I'll throw in on rt.perl.org, thanks!

Comment: @Arkady Kukarkin - filed yesterday: #114808

Answer (score 5):

This was a bug, and has now been fixed in blead by commits 7e0d5ad7c9cdb21b681e611b888acd41d34c4d05 and
c72077c4fff72b66cdde1621c62fb4fd383ce093.  This fix should be available in 5.17.5